# Rmd knits to html instead of PDF

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I have compiled an Rmd file that **should** knit to PDF, whereof the code is derived from another model which does knit to pdf. However, with the exact same yaml header parameters, the knitting defaults to HTML instead of pdf for the first model (When clicking 'knit to pdf'.  I am using R version 3.6.1.

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author:
- Piet en Henk
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
abstract: "This document provides the description of the used R code for ...."
geometry: "left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, headsep=0.4in"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: zenburn
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
header-includes:
- \usepackage{eso-pic}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{transparent}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{datetime}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{courier}
- \usepackage{placeins}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \numberwithin{figure}{section}
- \newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
- \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
- \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics{Company.png}}
- \fancyfoot[RO]{Company}
- \fancyfoot[L]{Version 1.0}

---
```{=latex}
% Trigger ToC creation in LaTeX
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}\normalsize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}\normalsize
\tableofcontents
```
\pagebreak
````

And the loggings from the Rmarkdown pane:

processing file: index.Rmd
|......................................................................| 100%
inline R code fragments

output file: index.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS index.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output index.html --lua-filter "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-36~1.1\library\bookdown\RMARKD~1\lua\CUSTOM~1.LUA" --lua-filter "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-36~1.1\library\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\PAGEBR~1.LUA" --lua-filter "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-36~1.1\library\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\LATEX-~1.LUA" --metadata-file "C:\Users\mpruijs\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpER5E5P\file2bec2a1279b1" --wrap preserve --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --template "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-36~1.1\library\bookdown\TEMPLA~1\GITBOO~1.HTM" --highlight-style pygments --number-sections --css style.css --include-in-header "C:\Users\mpruijs\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpER5E5P\rmarkdown-str2bec4d551488.html" --mathjax

Output created: index.html
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unable to identify current timezone 'C':
please set environment variable 'TZ'

Comment: When I click on "Knit to PDF", R is rendering a PDF document. Is it what you do as well?

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing, but it doesn't render PDF but HTML...

Comment: Can you please print the output messages from `R Markdown`  pane

Comment: Of course, sorry, added them to the question

Comment: When I use the first model, which does knit to pdf, I notice a difference in the markdown loggings which could be the issue:
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS index.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output index.tex 

So the first model has 'to latex' in the loggings and the second hasn't, while both have the same code...